# what callback do we get when file is cleared (i.e. Made empty) and saved in Minifilter?

Tags: c, windows, minifilter

I am Working on a minifilter to detect files write by some process in the **PreWrite** callback of **IRP_MJ_WRITE**. It works great when some files content is modified. But not getting PreWrite callback when the file content is modified and made to zero sizes. i.e select all then clear out the content and finally save the file. it is also kind of writing so why not getting a PreWrite callback?

How to prevent File writing(clear all content & save the file)?
or what callback do we get when file content is cleared(i.e becomes empty) and the file is saved?

As a beginner in minifilter, am I missing something or unaware of some concept?

Please guide/help me.

I will be very thankful to the Stackoverflow community.

Comment: Add [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exist 2 ways (how i know) for empty file (set it size to 0)

1. call [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with
   [`FileEndOfFileInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_end_of_file_information)

in this case `IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION` callback will be invoked. you need check that

`Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.FileInformationClass == FileEndOfFileInformation`. in this case `InfoBuffer` will point to [`FILE_END_OF_FILE_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_end_of_file_information) where new *EndOfFile* value

2. call [`NtCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntcreatefile) or [`IoCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-iocreatefile)

with *CreateDisposition* equal to
*FILE_OVERWRITE* or *FILE_OVERWRITE_IF* or *FILE_SUPERSEDE* (in this case file will be deleted and new empty file created with same name). the `IRP_MJ_CREATE` callback will be invoked. you need check:

```
PFLT_PARAMETERS Parameters = &Data->Iopb->Parameters;

ULONG Options = Parameters->Create.Options;
ULONG CreateDisposition = Options >> 24;

Options &= 0x00ffffff;
```

`CreateDisposition` value for `FILE_OVERWRITE` or `FILE_OVERWRITE_IF` or `FILE_SUPERSEDE`

Comment: Clearing File content and saving (Ctrl+A, Delete, Ctrl+S) is also kind of writing so why not getting a PreWrite callback of IRP_MJ_WRITE?

Comment: @jaykr no any writing here. here `IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION` with `FileEndOfFileInformation` and `EndOfFile.QuadPart == 0`

Comment: `IRP_MJ_WRITE` received when and only when client call `WriteFile` or direct send *IRP* with this major code. in your case this not exist

Comment: In the second case, If the existing file will be deleted and the new empty file created with the same name then why does the file Attribute(Created)'s Time remain the same.?so if the Created Attribute time remains the same then no new file is being created. I think

Comment: @jaykr - file deleted only if `FILE_SUPERSEDE` used. if used `FILE_OVERWRITE` or `FILE_OVERWRITE_IF` file not deleted but trancated to 0 size.